# juju bootstrap error no default environment found

Tags: juju

Everytime i type juju bootstrap .Error no default environment found keeps showing up. I was trying to configure maas.

This is my environments.yaml

```
juju: environments
environments:
maas:
type: maas
maas-server: 'http://{my ip address}:80/MAAS'
maas-oauth: 'c2cg7hTpzFuRmJjrBC:YH2ZEXVRKL46ttaDmq:beKeBjhYgWyxKk2gqqwaCx97xnmp4LJu'
admin-secret: 'nothing'
default-series: 'precise'
```

Answer (score 4):

Even with only one environment specified in environments.yaml, you still need to specify a default environment for juju to use.

You have 2 options to specify a default environment:

1. Using `default: <name>`, usually at the top of environments.yaml, without indentation (in your case, you'll need `default: maas`).
2. Using `juju switch <name>` on the command line (e.g. `juju switch maas`).

I hope this helps.